upper- and lower bounds of primes in intervals
Let's define two intervals $A =\{1,\dots,\frac{1}{4}N\}$ and $B =\{\frac{3}{4}N,\dots,N\}$. Let $\pi(A)$ be the counting function which counts the prime numbers in interval $A$. And similar, $\pi(B)$ the counting function for interval $B$.
Probably it's quite trivial, but are the following to statements true for all values of $N>N_1$?

$\pi(A) > \frac{1}{4} \times \pi(N)$
$\pi(B) < \frac{1}{4} \times \pi(N)$

I have checked them numerically for some small values of N. Statement (1) seems correct for all values of $N>22$ and (2) seems to be true for all values of $N>90$. If I want to use this as an argument in a proof, is it sufficient to say that both statement are true for $N>90$?

You can't really use this as an argument in a proof without, well, proving it first. Checking up to even some very large $N$ isn't sufficient for proof. That said, these statements seem likely; I imagine the PNT might give you a way to get to a proof, but I'm uncertain what that direction is. Have you tried anything other than checking various values of $N$?

The first statement can be reformulated as $\pi(\frac{N}{4})>\frac{\pi(N)}{4}$

@peter does that change anything?

Both of your inequalities are true, with the following showing this analytically for all $N$ larger than certain specific $N_1$ by using sufficiently tight explicit lower and upper bounds on the values of $\pi(x)$. In particular, from Wikipedia's Non-asymptotic bounds on the prime-counting function section, there's

Later in 2010, Dusart proved:36$\begin{aligned}{\frac {x}{\log x-1}}\;&<\;\pi (x)&&{\text{  for }}x\geq 5393\;,{\text{   and }}\\\pi (x)\;&<\;{\frac {x}{\log x-1.1}}&&{\text{  for }}x\geq 60184\;.\end{aligned}$

For all $x\ge 60184$, define the lower bound and upper bound prime number functions as
$$\pi_1(x) = \frac{x}{\log(x) - 1}, \;\; \pi_2(x) = \frac{x}{\log(x) - 1.1}$$

As indicated in Peter's comment, your first inequality can be stated as being
$$\pi\left(\frac{N}{4}\right) \gt \frac{\pi(N)}{4}$$
To prove this, it's sufficient to prove that the lower bound of the LHS is greater than the upper bound of the RHS, which is equivalent to showing their difference is positive. We have for all $N$ greater or equal to than
$$\frac{N_1}{4} = 60\text{,}184 \;\;\to\;\; N_1 = 240\text{,}736$$
that
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\pi_1\left(\frac{N}{4}\right) - \frac{\pi_2(N)}{4} & = \frac{\frac{N}{4}}{\log\left(\frac{N}{4}\right) - 1} - \frac{\frac{N}{4}}{\log(N) - 1.1} \\
& = \left(\frac{N}{4}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\log\left(\frac{N}{4}\right) - 1} - \frac{1}{\log(N) - 1.1}\right) \\
& = \left(\frac{N}{4}\right)\left(\frac{\log(N) - 1.1 - (\log(N) - \log(4) - 1)}{\left(\log\left(\frac{N}{4}\right) - 1\right)\left(\log(N) - 1.1\right)}\right) \\
& = \left(\frac{N}{4}\right)\left(\frac{\log(4) - 0.1}{\left(\log\left(\frac{N}{4}\right) - 1\right)\left(\log(N) - 1.1\right)}\right) \\
& \gt 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
since $\log(4) - 0.1 \approx 1.3$. Thus, your first inequality is true for all such values of $N$.

Your second conjecture is that
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\pi(B) & \lt \frac{\pi(N)}{4} \\
\pi(N) - \pi\left(\frac{3N}{4}\right) & \lt \frac{\pi(N)}{4} \\
\frac{3\pi(N)}{4} & \lt \pi\left(\frac{3N}{4}\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Similar to before, it's sufficient to prove the upper bound of the LHS is less than the lower bound of the RHS, which is equivalent to showing their difference is negative. We have for all $N$ greater than
$$\frac{3N_1}{4} = 60\text{,}184 \;\;\to\;\; N_1 = 80\text{,}245.\bar{3}$$
that
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{3\pi_2(N)}{4} - \pi_1\left(\frac{3N}{4}\right) & = \frac{\frac{3N}{4}}{\log(N) - 1.1} - \frac{\frac{3N}{4}}{\log\left(\frac{3N}{4}\right) - 1} \\
& = \left(\frac{3N}{4}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\log(N) - 1.1} - \frac{1}{\log\left(\frac{3N}{4}\right) - 1}\right) \\
& = \left(\frac{3N}{4}\right)\left(\frac{\log(N) + \log(.75) - 1 - (\log(N) - 1.1)}{(\log(N) - 1.1)\left(\log\left(\frac{3N}{4}\right) - 1\right)}\right) \\
& = \left(\frac{3N}{4}\right)\left(\frac{\log(.75) + .1}{(\log(N) - 1.1)\left(\log\left(\frac{3N}{4}\right) - 1\right)}\right) \\
& \lt 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
because $\log(.75) + .1 \approx -0.19$. This means your second inequality is true for all such values of $N$.

This shows that your inequalities are both true for all $N \gt N_1$ where $N_1 = 240\text{,}735$. To prove they are true for all $N \gt 90$, it's sufficient to check all intermediate values of $N$, likely with a computer program. Although it's not particularly difficult to write and run such a program, since you've already done numerical work with these inequalities, I'm leaving it to you to use that to do this checking.
